# How to change the hue/saturation/brightness for only a part of the image in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

I already know how to change the aforementioned settings for the entire image.

[image]

But what if I only want to change it for a specific part of her face, or for an arbitrary non-rectangular area? How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This what the selection tools are for. For instance you use the lasso tool to draw a polygon around the face, add some feathering (Select>Feather or use the tools' feathering option), and then do the color changes (hat will only apply to the selection area).

Comment: You can also apply the [Intelligent Scissors Tool](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-iscissors.html), like in this [example](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-separate.html).